# Rails 7 Session not Persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I'm having trouble getting my session on Rails 7 to persist. I'm not even redirecting at any point, just staying on the one page.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

    include ActionController::Cookies
    
end
```

application.rb

```
require_relative "boot"

require "rails/all"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module CsmBack
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 7.0

    # Configuration for the application, engines, and railties goes here.
    #
    # These settings can be overridden in specific environments using the files
    # in config/environments, which are processed later.
    #
    # config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
    # config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("extras")

        # Must add these lines!
    # Adding back cookies and session middleware
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_namespace_key'

    # Use SameSite=Strict for all cookies to help protect against CSRF
    config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :strict
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
  def login
        if session[:user_id]
            return render json: {errors: "Username or Password Wrong"}
        end
        
    

        user=User.find_by(username: params[:username])

        if user&.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            render json: user
        else
            render json: {errors: "Username or Password Wrong"}
        end
    end
```

If that last one worked, I should be able to click the button to trigger it twice in a row and get different values, but I'm not even getting that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be throwing an error to the client side if they try to log in without logging out first.
According to what I see here, your server-side code, (however off it might seem) is fine. You might want to look at your client side, maybe set up a proxy